# Line chart + grouped bar chart with different frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

I have 5 time series (class `pandas.core.series.Series`) with different frequencies and I want to make this chart:
[desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZbyf.png)

```
df1 (daily data, only working days) 
Date   exchange_rate_daily
2013-01-02  25.225
2013-01-03  25.26
2013-01-04  25.35
2013-01-07  25.535
2013-01-08  25.58
2013-01-09  25.53
2013-01-10  25.63
2013-01-11  25.615
2013-01-14  25.615
2013-01-15  25.61
2013-01-16  25.58
2013-01-17  25.54
2013-01-18  25.63
2013-01-21  25.625
       
df2 (monthly data for 2 time series)
Date intervention_monthly client_monthly
2013-01-01  0.6   0.67273
2013-02-01  0.2   0.04
2013-03-01  0.4   0.17443
2013-04-01  0.3   0.53883
2013-05-01  0.7   -0.0647
2013-06-01  0.2   0.20103
2013-07-01  0.0   0.22846
2013-08-01  0.0   -0.2611
2013-09-01  0.0   0.16002
2013-10-01  0.0  -0.10967
2013-11-01  7.4  -0.31122
```

Line chart:

X-axis: `date_exchangerate_daily` (size = 2198, daily date i.e. `2013-01-02 00:00:00`, but only business days - no weekends, no holidays)

Y-axis (left): `exchangerate_daily (size = 2198, daily exchange rate)

My code for this line chart works well. See below:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax1.plot(date_exchangerate_daily, exchangerate_daily, color="k", label="Exchange rate (daily)", linewidth=2)
ax1.legend(loc = "upper left")
```

Grouped bar chart:

X-axis: `date_operations_monthly` (size = 107, monthly date e.g. `2013-01-01 00:00:00`)

Y-axis (right): `intervention_monthly` (size = 107, monthly data)

Y-axis (right): `client_monthly` (size = 107, monthly data)

```
x = np.arange(len(date_operations_monthly))
width = 0.1
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
rects1 = ax2.bar(x - width/2, intervention_monthly, width, label='Intervention (monthly)')
rects2 = ax2.bar(x + width/2, client_monthly, width, label='Client operation (monthly)')
ax2.set_xticks(x)
ax2.set_xticklabels(date_operations_monthly2, rotation = 70)
ax2.legend(loc = "upper right")
```

And I get this chart:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOGsI.png)

If I plot the charts separately, I get the right charts. So there is a problem with combining these two charts. And I guess the problem is that the data frequency is different and then the size of the dates series (daily x monthly date) I want to plot on the X-axis is different. Is there please any solutions for this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome here! Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and write a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no data available, I used the stock price data and created a bar chart using the closing price, volume, and 1/2 of the volume for the other bar chart.
The matplotlib time series is based on the Gregorian calendar, so it needs to be converted. See this for more [details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Date   exchange_rate_daily
2013-01-02  25.225
2013-01-03  25.26
2013-01-04  25.35
2013-01-07  25.535
2013-01-08  25.58
2013-01-09  25.53
2013-01-10  25.63
2013-01-11  25.615
2013-01-14  25.615
2013-01-15  25.61
2013-01-16  25.58
2013-01-17  25.54
2013-01-18  25.63
2013-01-21  25.625
'''

data1 = '''
Date intervention_monthly client_monthly
2013-01-01  0.6   0.67273
2013-02-01  0.2   0.04
2013-03-01  0.4   0.17443
2013-04-01  0.3   0.53883
2013-05-01  0.7   -0.0647
2013-06-01  0.2   0.20103
2013-07-01  0.0   0.22846
2013-08-01  0.0   -0.2611
2013-09-01  0.0   0.16002
2013-10-01  0.0  -0.10967
2013-11-01  7.4  -0.31122
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), delim_whitespace=True)
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax1.plot(mdates.date2num(df1['Date']), df1['exchange_rate_daily'], color="k", label="Exchange rate (daily)", linewidth=2)
ax1.legend(loc = "upper left")

#x = np.arange(len(df2))
width = 0.5
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
rects1 = ax2.bar(mdates.date2num(df2['Date']) - 1, df2['intervention_monthly'], width, label='Intervention (monthly)')
rects2 = ax2.bar(mdates.date2num(df2['Date']) + 1, df2['client_monthly'], width, label='Client operation (monthly)')
all_dates = sorted(df1['Date'][::5].tolist()+df2['Date'].tolist())
all_dates = mdates.date2num(all_dates)
ax2.set_xticks(all_dates)
ax2.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in all_dates])
ax2.legend(loc = "upper right") 
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Unfortunately at this part of code: x = mdates.date2num(df.index) i got this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Comment: The code that generated this error converts the index of the data frame (date in this example) to a date format that can be handled by matplotlib. If you get an error here, it means that either the data before conversion is not in pandas date format, or it is not an index. Did this happen in all my code? Once you run it in all the codes and see how each data is converted, you will have a better understanding. Also, this question has been treated as a duplicate, but please let me know so I can help you resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, those similar questions don't answer my question. Your code is fine, but your loaded dataframe size is different. I am sorry, I did not show you my data sample. I will do it in next comment.

Comment: I added the datasample to my question

Comment: The data has been provided and I have updated the answers using it. The method has not been changed; the data in df1 is daily data, so the scales overlapped, so I have corrected them to 5-day intervals.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but it can be accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but still. Even though I use pd.to_datetime, I still got AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal' at the part ax1.plot(mdates.date2num

I got this same error also when I run your code.

Comment: If you get an error when you run my code, it seems to be a difference in environment. My matplotlib is the latest version of 3.4.3. What version are you using?

Comment: Yes :-) It was the problem. So thank you very much once again!